# Fluid Player does not load VAST

Tags: javascript, xml, vast

I'm trying to add a preRoll ad to my content video with [Fluid Player](https://docs.fluidplayer.com/).
According to the docs I have to:

1. Add VAST options to the player config
2. Place the VAST xml file on the same domain
3. Make sure the content-type is either application/xml or text/xml

Here is what I've done:

**HTML + JS code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fluid Player</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.fluidplayer.com/v2/current/fluidplayer.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.fluidplayer.com/v2/current/fluidplayer.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<video id='my-video'>
    <source src='https://my.domain.com/video/sample.mp4' type='video/mp4'/>
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
  fluidPlayer('my-video', {
    layoutControls: {
      playButtonShowing: false,
      autoPlay: false,
      mute: false,
      keyboardControl: false,
      fillToContainer: true,
      controlBar: {
        autoHide: false, // Default false
      },
      vastOptions: {
        vastTimeout: 5000,
        adText: 'advertisement',
        adList: [
          {
            roll: 'preRoll',
            vastTag: 'https://my.domain.com/xml/vastLinear.xml'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**VAST xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VAST version="3.0">
  <Ad id="1">
    <InLine>
      <AdSystem>Example</AdSystem>
      <AdTitle/>
      <Impression id="example"><![CDATA[http://example.com/view?tracking_event=impression&idzone=9999999]]></Impression>
      <Impression id="example2"><![CDATA[http://example.com/view2?tracking_event=impression&idzone=9999999]]></Impression>
      <Creatives>
        <Creative sequence="1" id="1">
          <Linear skipoffset="00:00:03">
            <TrackingEvents>
                <Tracking event="progress" offset="00:00:01.000"><![CDATA[http://example.com/view?tracking_event=progress&progress=00:00:01.000&idzone=9999999]]></Tracking>
                <Tracking event="progress" offset="00:00:02.000"><![CDATA[http://example.com/view?tracking_event=progress&progress=00:00:02.000&idzone=9999999]]></Tracking>
                <Tracking event="progress" offset="00:00:05.000"><![CDATA[http://example.com/view?tracking_event=progress&progress=00:00:05.000&idzone=9999999]]></Tracking>
                <Tracking event="progress" offset="00:00:05.000"><![CDATA[http://example.com/view2?tracking_event=progress&progress=00:00:05.000&idzone=9999999]]></Tracking>
                <Tracking event="progress" offset="00:00:09.000"><![CDATA[http://example.com/view?tracking_event=progress&progress=00:00:09.000&idzone=9999999]]></Tracking>
                <Tracking event="start"><![CDATA[http://example.com/view?tracking_event=start&idzone=9999999]]></Tracking>
                <Tracking event="firstQuartile"><![CDATA[http://example.com/view?tracking_event=firstQuartile&idzone=9999999]]></Tracking>
                <Tracking event="midpoint"><![CDATA[http://example.com/view?tracking_event=midpoint&idzone=9999999]]></Tracking>
                <Tracking event="midpoint"><![CDATA[http://example.com/view2?tracking_event=midpoint&idzone=9999999]]></Tracking>
                <Tracking event="midpoint"><![CDATA[http://example.com/view3?tracking_event=midpoint&idzone=9999999]]></Tracking>
                <Tracking event="thirdQuartile"><![CDATA[http://example.com/view?tracking_event=thirdQuartile&idzone=9999999]]></Tracking>
                <Tracking event="complete"><![CDATA[http://example.com/view?tracking_event=complete&idzone=9999999]]></Tracking>
            </TrackingEvents>
            <VideoClicks>
                <ClickThrough><![CDATA[http://example.com/]]></ClickThrough>
                <ClickTracking><![CDATA[http://example.com/view?tracking_event=click&idzone=9999999]]></ClickTracking>
                <ClickTracking><![CDATA[http://example.com/view2?tracking_event=click&idzone=9999999]]></ClickTracking>
            </VideoClicks>
            <MediaFiles>
              <MediaFile delivery="progressive" type="video/mp4"><![CDATA[http://my.domain.com/videos/pre-ad.mp4]]></MediaFile>
            </MediaFiles>
          </Linear>
        </Creative>
      </Creatives>
    </InLine>
  </Ad>
</VAST>
```

The player loads the sample.mp4 just fine, but I can't see the ad or any attempt to fetch the VAST file on the network tab.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: hi did you solve this?